Is there an equivalent in Latin for "Brown-eyed"?
I know that the the colours in Latin aren't like today, but how would they describe someone Brown-eyed or juts tell that someone has brown eyes? I saw adjectives like "fuscus, fulvus, pullus" but I didn't see anything like "brown eyes".

Are you familiar with the genitive or ablative of quality (genetivus/ablativus qualitatis)?

The genitive, yes. But I can't find the "word" to describe brown.

How about spādīx?

Eyes with the exact colour brown may not have been recorded in Classical Latin but there are expressions recorded with similar colours, and from which eyes can be assigned a colour.
From  Titus Maccius Plautus, Mercator 640 The Merchant

subnigris oculis

Translated by Boris Dunsch

with darkish eyes

From Marcus Terentius Varro, Res Rusticae 2.2.4.4  referring to sheep

ravis oculis

Translation by W. D. Hooper et H. B. Ash Book II Chapter 2 verse 4.

grey eyes

In the Lewis & Short Dictionary ravus is noted as meaning either grey, grey yellow or tawny, a colour between flavos (flavus) and caesios (casieus)
For dark or jet black eyes nigris oculis and nigris pernigris also exist.  If instead you wish to use fuscus -a -um or pullus -a -um as brown

fuscis oculis , pullis occulis

As to what colours mean exactly there is this Stack Exchange question.
One of the comments to the question described 'fulvus as "tawny, lion-colored" - meaning that it would be used to describe a lion' (the tawny colour brown of a lion). This comment in turn referred to a web page with descriptions of colour which is now only available on the Internet Wayback machineConcordance to the Colours used by Elias Magnus Fries. Botanical colours in Latin (assigned post medieval) are described/listed by William T. Stearn in his book Botanical Latin 1983 3rd Ed.
